# Can't print out the result of conditional %ELSE in a SAS Macro

Tags: sas

Apologies is this is incredibly basic, I am new to SAS. I am experimenting with macros and I have written the described code. I expect it to print 'not_true' to the log 3 times, but it doesn't for some reason. I can't see what is wrong with it, I just want it to print something off so I can see whether it actually works...

```
%macro check_condition(val);

%if &val = 10 %then %return;

%else %put 'not_true';

run;

%mend;

%check_condition(6);

%check_condition(7);

%check_condition(8);
```

> 'not_true' 'not_true' 'not_true'

in the log

Comment: Works fine for me.  Start a new SAS session and submit it again.

Comment: Thanks, that was confusing the hell out of me because it made perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new and experimenting, the likely scenario is that an earlier submit was of code that did not contain a `%mend;` statement.  When that happens, all subsequent submitted code will be considered a part of the open macro awaiting it's `%mend;`

Answer (score 0):

I run the code and it put 3 times in log like below...

```
24         %macro check_condition(val);
25         
26         %if &val = 10 %then %return;
27         
28         %else %put 'not_true';
29         
30         run;
31         
32         %mend;
33         
34         %check_condition(6);
'not_true'
35         
36         %check_condition(7);
'not_true'
37         
38         %check_condition(8);
'not_true'
39
```